# Building MusicStore ASP.NET Sample using Docker Fails with Error CS0246

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-for-windows, docker-build

I am trying to run the MusicStore asp.net application as a demo for a windows container environment. I found [this Github article](https://github.com/friism/Musicstore?fbclid=IwAR1KINCfnXDQM4mlJ3BO2XuSxaPtnm3952Bh5OQqZSUexpu3eOKtUotDZFg) detailing the steps required to build and run it as containers.

However, every time I try to build the app it exits with the below output. May I know the reason behind it and how can I resolve the issue.

```
Restore completed in 8.64 min for C:\app\samples\MusicStore\musicstore.csproj.
Models\MusicStoreContext.cs(6,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\app\samples\MusicStore\musicstore.csproj]
Models\MusicStoreContext.cs(8,18): error CS0311: The type 'MusicStore.Models.ApplicationUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'IdentityDbContext<TUser>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MusicStore.Models.ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser'. [C:\app\samples\MusicStore\musicstore.csproj]
ForTesting\Mocks\MicrosoftAccount\TestMicrosoftAccountEvents.cs(51,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OAuthRedirectToAuthorizationContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\app\samples\MusicStore\musicstore.csproj]
ForTesting\Mocks\Twitter\TestTwitterEvents.cs(44,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TwitterRedirectToAuthorizationEndpointContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\app\samples\MusicStore\musicstore.csproj]
ForTesting\Mocks\Facebook\TestFacebookEvents.cs(50,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OAuthRedirectToAuthorizationContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\app\samples\MusicStore\musicstore.csproj]
ForTesting\Mocks\Google\TestGoogleEvents.cs(50,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OAuthRedirectToAuthorizationContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\app\samples\MusicStore\musicstore.csproj]
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; dotnet publish --output /out --configuration Release --framework netcoreapp2.0 --runtime win10-x64 .\samples\MusicStore' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

P.S This is the output of the .csproj file. According to that the application use ASP.NET Core.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <Import Project="..\..\build\dependencies.props" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Description>Music store application on ASP.NET Core</Description>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);DEMO</DefineConstants>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x86;win7-x64;linux-x64;osx-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="ForTesting\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" Condition=" '$(PublishForTesting)' != 'true' "/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreModule" Version="$(AspNetCoreModuleVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core or ASP.NET? You've tagged your question with both, and the Github project you referenced is ASP.NET, not ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Have you opened the solution in Visual Studio? If you did, in the project MusicStore, under Dependencies > Nuget, do you see items that have yellow triangles?

Comment: @ChrisPratt I have modified the tags as you suggested. according to the project file, I think its using .net core. Kindly look into the modified question.

Comment: Yes. This is Core. However, I believe you've likely copied in code from the sample project (which is ASP.NET - not Core) and that code, while similar, will be different in Core, because things like EF/EF Core and ASP.NET Identity/ASP.NET Core Identity are differently implemented.

Comment: @KristianneNerona No, I have not. I am not an active developer for quite some time now. However, that's what I'm planning to do next. :/

Comment: @Sajirupee You are encountering those errors because you are missing the nuget packages. Read a bit about it using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages)